# SSH client takes 100 seconds to connect to machine with 17ms ping time

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, cygwin, connection

I'm trying to SSH from one computer of mine, A, to another, B, over a (wireless) LAN. They have the same netmask, get their lease the same way etc. The client A is Devuan Linux, the "server" B is a Windows 10 machine, running Cygwin's SSH server. I should mention B has a bunch of corporate spyware/malware/whatever installed by my employer, a large corporation.

Now, I can SSH from B to itself, from A to itself (`ssh localhost` works fine on both machines) and from B to A - quickly. When I nmap B from A, it takes a lot of time, but eventually the results come up and port 22 is listed as being open. When I try SSH’ing from A to B, after having added a public to my user on B which would avoid the need for entering a password, **it takes about a 100 seconds to connect**. The delay remains similar if I disconnect and reconnect

I have root on A and am an admin on B. What can I do to figure out why the connection fails and to enable it (Without reinstalling parts of Windows, changing drivers etc. - which I'm not allowed to do)?

Additional information:

```
$ nmap 192.168.1.7 -p 22 -Pn -sV
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-08 22:27 IDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.7
Host is up (0.064s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 8.2 (protocol 2.0)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at (URL SNIPPED).
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.86 seconds
```

and also:

```
$ ssh -vv 123456@192.168.1.7
OpenSSH_8.0p1 Debian-6, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/joeuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.7 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.7 [192.168.1.7] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0p1 Debian-6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.7:22 as '123456'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:a0D2ZMccMC0ixetNhUYcsSvIz5ElYHA73ZBVbcbYo0s
debug1: Host '192.168.1.7' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/joeuser/.ssh/known_hosts:101
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:V1OMM1prAT2pmIi6jPpCANaB3+oIrY0n4eAHoxuNW94 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:IhdLYNaDrqcQjxpRmPW/ppA3u3R5koPudZMDcRy/y6w agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:V1OMM1prAT2pmIi6jPpCANaB3+oIrY0n4eAHoxuNW94 agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:V1OMM1prAT2pmIi6jPpCANaB3+oIrY0n4eAHoxuNW94 agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.7 ([192.168.1.7]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/123456/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/123456/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IL
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Fri May  8 23:38:58 2020 from 192.168.1.5
```

Long pauses after:

- "local version string",
- "we sent a publickey packet"
- "Server accepts key ... RSA"
- "channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768"
- "Last login"

Comment: 100 seconds looks as the Cygwin machine is looking data somewhere else. Have you a running Cygserver ? If not try it as it caches some user data that are usuful in domain user connections.

Comment: @matzeri: I'm using the default Cygwin mechanism for installing an ssh Windows service. Does that mean I have a "running cygserver"? Also, there's no user data that takes it 100 seconds to get to; and remember SSH'ing from B to B is instantaneous.

Comment: cygserver is an auxiliary service: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html It is installed in similar way to the sshd demon with `/usr/bin/cygserver-config`. It helps in some case with domain users that have long delay in recovering data from Domain server.

Comment: To debug from server side you can use the hint at the end of http://holt.oso.chalmers.se/hgs/hgs.man/CYGWIN-HOW-TO.html .It allows to log on file as the current default probably is sending the sshd logs to windows. I tested on my PC and the log goes to `/var/log/messages`. Probably you will need to increase the `LogLevel`

Comment: @matzeri: It seems I might not actually be logging as a local user after all - and I am indeed "not close" to the domain server. I started cygserver, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you create a real local user and see if with that you can remove the time lags ?